# How can I legally access object with wrong alignment using pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, alignment

I need to read/write objects using pointers to wrongly aligned locations. I don't want to 
use `pragma pack` or other compiler-specific features.

At first, I tried this:

```
char arr[sizeof (float) * 2];
*(float *)(arr + 1) = 1.0;
```

But this code causes UB because it violates strict aliasing rule.

The next code also will not work without `pragma pack` because compiler might insert a padding after `: 8;`.

```
union
{
    struct
    {
        char arr[sizeof (float) * 2]
    } a;
    struct
    {
        : 8;
        float val;
    } b;
} data;
data.b.val = 1.0;
```

---

So, can I legally access object with pointer to wrongly aligned location?

I can copy objects byte by byte to needed location (or memcpy), but I think it will be slow, so I'm trying to find another solutions.

---

Update: Yes I know about `alignas`, but it can only increase alignment, not decrease it.

Comment: "but I think it will be slow". Do it with memcpy's, optimize later if it becomes a problem.

Comment: I recall there being an exception for `char` array allocations in that they could be `reinterpret_cast` to another pointer type without UB. Maybe I'm making that up.

Comment: Do you know `alignas`?

Comment: You think it will be slow, or you know? Compilers can be quite good about `memcpy` calls with small constant size. Check the assembly.

Comment: `memcpy` is slow (if it is) because it can copy unaligned data. You can't have both.

Comment: @Columbo `alignas` can only increase alignment, it can't decrease it.

Comment: @cdhowie: I believe you're right, `*(float *)(arr + 1) = 1.0;` doesn't violate strict aliasing. It's still not safe, though, if the implementation has an alignment requirement for `float`, because then I think just creating an unaligned `float*` is UB, but using it sure is. You can't even be sure the alignment is wrong, since you don't know what the alignment will be of an automatic variable of type `char[N]` ;-)

Comment: @cdhowie: There is such an exception. Though in the opposite direction only.

Comment: C is not some high-level language that hides behind "safe" abstractions and rigid types. It's portable assembly code. It's not the C compiler's job to stop you from shooting yourself in the foot. If you tell it to access unaligned bytes, it will just access unaligned bytes. That may cause it to generate more/slower code on some processors. And of course it will be totally unportable. The compiler *might* give you a warning. But still, you're the boss.

Comment: @Lee: " it will just access unaligned bytes" -- not necessarily. It's undefined behavior to use an incorrectly-aligned pointer. The reason there's no requirement that accessing unaligned addresses works, is that there are plenty of CPUs on which satisfying that would require emitted the slower code for almost all accesses via a `float*`, just in case it's unaligned. x86 cracks this problem in that the same instruction is fast when the address is aligned, but still works when the address is unaligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always access an object as an array of `unsigned char` in C (**not** the other way around though).
As `char` has size and alignment 1, that allows you to access things however you want.

Be aware though that in C++ things aren't quite that nice:
Unless the type is trivially copyable, a byte-copy is not allowed.